# need help in grep (BASH)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

I try to make a tool to get list of proxies and You have downloaded Index for one of the free proxy sites I use this :

```
wget http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/https/ping/all
```

and outputs something like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTg1LjExNC4xMzcuMTQ="))</script></td><td style=""><span class="fport" style=''>12195</span></td><td><small>HTTPS</small></td><td class="left"><div style="padding-left:2px"><img src="/flags/blank.gif" class="flag flag-ua" alt="Ukraine" /> <a href="/en/proxylist/country/UA/all/ping/all">Ukraine</a></div></td><td class="small"><small></small></td><td class="small"><small></small></td><td class="small"><small>High anonymity</small></td><td> <i class="icon-black icon-question-sign"></i></td><td><small>2.4%</small><div class="progress"><div class="fill" style="width:4%;background-color:red;"></div></div></td><td><div style="padding-left:5px"><small>649 ms</small> <div class="progress"><div class="fill" style="width:94%;background-color:#A5DA74;;"></div></div></div></td><td><small>8 hours ago</small></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center" class="left"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTYxLjk3LjEzOC4yMzg="))</script></td><td style=""><span class="fport" style=''>3128</span></td><td>
```

As you can see the IP is encrypted in base64 and port is normal

I try to grep base64 codes first and this is work ↓

```
echo (outputs) | grep -Eo '("[A-Za-z0-9]{12,30}[=]{0,2}")' | cut -d '"' -f2
```

and I try this code to get ports ↓

```
echo (output) | grep -Eo "(class=\"fport\" style=''>[0-9]{1,9})"  | cut -d '>' -f2
```

how can I mix it and make it like that

```
(base64 code):(port)
```

and after that I wanna decrypt the base64 code and make it look like :

```
IP:PORT
```

Comment: Asking for "fast answers" is frowned on -- not just here but in general; see http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent. You'll also get a better response (more, higher-quality answers; fewer downvotes) if you take the time to come up with a title that accurately describes your specific problem.

Comment: ...in general, the focus of writing both questions and answers here is not just to help the person who first asked about a problem, but to help _everyone else with the same problem in the future_. That means both parties are expected to take their time and focus on writing both the best possible question and the best possible answer, to best help others learn from both question and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1st step

`base64` is not an encryption, but an encoding. If you are working on
Linux or other Unix-variants, the command `base64`, base64-encoder/decoder,
will be pre-installed. If not, it will be easily installed with your
OS-dependent package manager.
Then please try to execute:

```
base64 -d <<< "MTg1LjExNC4xMzcuMTQ="
```

It will output:

```
185.114.137.14
```

#### 2nd step

Then we can combine the base64 decoder with your command pipeline.
The problem is base64-coding ignores newlines and we need to process
the result of the pipeline line by line. Assuming the variable `$output`
holds the output of the `wget` command, please try:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    base64 -d <<< "$line"
    echo
done < <(echo "$output" | grep -Eo '("[A-Za-z0-9]{12,30}[=]{0,2}")' | cut -d '"' -f2)
```

It will print something like:

```
185.114.137.14
161.97.138.238
```

The `<(command)` notation is a process substitution and the output of
`echo .. grep .. cut` pipeline is fed to the `while` loop via stdin
and the `while` loop processes the base64-encoded strings line by line.

#### 3rd step

Now we want to merge the IPs and PORTs in a format of `IP:PORT`.
We can make use of `paste` command. The final script will be:

```
paste -d ":" <(
while IFS= read -r line; do
    base64 -d <<< "$line"
    echo
done < <(echo "$output" | grep -Eo '("[A-Za-z0-9]{12,30}[=]{0,2}")' | cut -d '"' -f2)
) \
<(echo "$output" | grep -Eo "(class=\"fport\" style=''>[0-9]{1,9})"  | cut -d '>' -f2)
```

Output:

```
185.114.137.14:12195
161.97.138.238:3128
```

The `paste` command takes filenames as arguments. Here we make use
of process substitution again in a manner as: `paste <(command1) <(command2)`
which saves to create temporary files.